# Configure PHP and mysql connection under linux

Tags: php, mysql

I encounter this problem when configure PHP and mysql on my linux box (Fedora 14).

The problem is when I invoke mysqli_connect(), an error issues:

**Call to undefined function mysqli_connect().**

while call to **mysql_connect()** works fine.

I install PHP and mysql manually and also turn on the flag `--with-mysql` when installing PHP. Can't figure out where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php says:

> To use MySQL Native Driver with mysqli you need to configure the PHP source code using the --with-mysqli=mysqlnd option, prior to building PHP.

In other words, `--with-mysql` is for a different module (which, as you note, works fine).

Answer (score 4):

Mysql-**i** is not Mysql, these are 2 distinct PHP modules and MySQL APIs. Have a look at [PHP's documentation regarding the mysqli installation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. So the only solution to my problem is reinstalling PHP?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: Yes. You need to re-do all the steps since ./configure

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: Yes, you need an additional configure-parameter for PHP to compile the mysqli extension. According to the PHP docs it should be `--with-mysqli=mysqlnd`.

Answer (score 3):

If `yum` is an option for you, you can simply run the following to install the mysqli extenstion:

```
yum install php-mysqli
```

**EDIT:** Marc B informs that mysqli is included in the core php rpm on Fedora 14. Simply install php via yum (after removing your manual install) with `yum install php`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've followed your advice, but does not work. Maybe I should reinstall the whole PHP.

Comment: Fedora 14 doesn't have a seperate mysqli package, it's included in the core php rpm.

Comment: Good info, Marc. That means he should just install php itself via yum.